# Channel field not showing on page with embedded template using Multi-Site Manager

Tags: templates, multi-site-manager, channel, fields, embeds

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 with Multisite Manager. I have one template embedded within another. The parent template is pulling data from 2 sites, and I would like certain information to show up depending on how many results there are from a channel:entries call. However, when one of the sites has results, the embed show correctly, but when the other site has results, the embedded template shows up, but the field results do not.

**Here is the parent template:**

```
{exp:channel:entries  site="default_site|characterized" orderby="entry_date" channel="events" sort="asc" status="next event|open" show_future_entries="yes"}
    {if total_results == "2"}
        {embed="home/side_bar_2" side_box_1_sm="{side_box_1_sm}" side_box_1_lg="{side_box_1_lg}" side_box_1_link="{side_box_1_link}"}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Here is the embedded template:**

```
{exp:channel:entries  site="default_site" orderby="entry_date" channel="home" sort="asc" status="open" show_future_entries="yes"}
    <a href="http://{embed:side_box_1_link}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{embed:side_box_1_sm}"/>
    </a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When the "characterized" site has 2 results, the embedded template works just fine. When the "default_site" has 2 results, the embedded template shows up with no values in the channel fields. when I look at the source code, it just shows

```
<a href="http://" target="_blank">
    <img src=""/>           
</a>
```

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try adding both sites in embed channel tag? site="default_site|characterized" as I can see you have only default_site

Comment: hi @Davor - for the embed, I do not want it to pull from "home" channel on the characterized site, so that's why it is not listed. however, i tried your suggestion, just to test it out, and it doesn't change my results. anything else you might try?